# Formatting string in Nlog message for a c# application

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to format the info message string in my c# application. I am using Nlog. This is how I am setting the formatting

```
  LogMessage($"Invalid arguments. Please ensure the arguments must contain correct format. For e.g order 20230829\t\t\t {Environment.NewLine} order {Environment.NewLine} trade 20230829 {Environment.NewLine} trade", LogMessageType.Info);
```

I have trying \t but that is making subtle difference and would have to insert too many for it to come close. Does anybody know a better way

At the moment I am getting the following output

```
2023-11-13 21:02:11.952 INFO    [MemberDataDailyMigration.Program] Invalid arguments. Please ensure the arguments must contain correct format. For e.g order 20230829            
 order 
 trade 20230829 
 trade
```

This is the desired output

```
2023-11-13 21:05:03.548 INFO    [MemberDataDailyMigration.Program] Invalid arguments. Please ensure the arguments must contain correct format. For e.g order 20230829 
                                                                                                                                                       order 
                                                                                                                                                       trade 20230829 
                                                                                                                                                       trade
```